# How to get the coordinates of the extrema from a plot?

Tags: plotting

I generated a number of plots. Let us assume that we now have these plots simply as an image. How do I get the coordinates of the extrema in this image?

I am interested in getting the coordinates as pairs of x and y, for each color in the plot.

Here is an example of such an image:

[image]

Comment: You mean a `Graphics`-object  or a pixel image?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I'm pretty sure they mean they have just a pixel image, which would complicate things a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If "image" is a Graphics-object try

```
pic = Plot[{Sin[x]/x, Exp[-.1 x] Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 20}]  (*two functions*) 

lines = Cases[pic, Line[p_] -> p, Infinity] (*get the points*)
```

Evaluate all extrema and plot

```
extrema = Map[Cases[
Partition[#, 3,1], {{_, a_}, p : {_, b_}, {_, c_}} /; a < b && c < b || a > b && c > b -> p] &, lines] 
Show[pic, Graphics[Point[extrema ]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I assume that I no longer have or know the function that resulted in the plots. I only have the "image".

Comment: I didn't use the knowledge of the function! One questiom : Are you looking for all extrema or only the global?

Comment: All the extrema.

Answer (score 4):

If "image" is a pixel image 
(named `pic` , **sorry, don't know how to include `pic="image"` in the coding** ) try:

```
dc = Rest@DominantColors[pic] (* dominant colors without white*)

curves = Map[ListPlot[PixelValuePositions[pic, #, .1 ],Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> #] &, dc] (* three colored curves *)
```

Get the points of the different curves

```
points = Cases[curves  , Point[pi_] -> pi, Infinity];
```

...see my first answer

Answer (score 3):

Ulrich's approach for a Graphics-object misses the end points. You can use [`FindPeaks`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindPeaks.html) to also catch the end points.

```
pic = Plot[{Sin[x]/x, Exp[-.1 x] Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 20}];  (*two functions*)

lines = Cases[pic, Line[p_] -> p, Infinity]; (*get the points*)

max = Flatten[(#[[FindPeaks[#[[All, 2]]][[All, 1]]]] & /@ lines), 1];

min = Flatten[(#[[FindPeaks[(# /. {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} :> {x, -y})[[All,
             2]]][[All, 1]]]] & /@ lines), 1];

Show[pic, Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Red, Point[max],
   Blue, Point[min]}]
```

[image]

Comment: @ BobHanlon Thanks, I didn't know `FindPeaks`